# How to back triggers to work after programmatically setting property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I want to set the background color of the control just for the time when left mouse button is pressed on it, then I want this control to back to its normal behavior (triggers for MouseOver etc.). But when I override the property in code-behind, triggers will stop working. How to fix it? I tried setting property to null on MouseUp event, but it didn't work anyway.

The code:

```
private void Item_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListBoxItem;
    item.Background = Application.Current.Resources["BlueLightBrush"];
}
```

After setting `Background` that way, it stays the same for next time I will set it (no changes will be done by triggers)

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Please post code.  Otherwise people are just guessing.

Comment: Can't you just make another Trigger for `IsPressed`?

Comment: There is no `IsPressed` property for `ListBoxItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted via attached property:

```
public static class ListBoxItemAttachedProperties
{
    public static bool GetIsMouseDown(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsMouseDownProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsMouseDown(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsMouseDownProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseDownProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMouseDown", typeof(bool), typeof(UIElementAttachedProperties), new PropertyMetadata(false));

}
```

code-behind:

```
private void Item_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
    listBoxItem.SetValue(ListBoxItemAttachedProperties.IsMouseDownProperty, true);
}

private void Item_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
    listBoxItem.SetValue(ListBoxItemAttachedProperties.IsMouseDownProperty, false);
}
```

xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"> 
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BlueDarkBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="local:ListBoxItemAttachedProperties.IsMouseDown" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueLightBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```